How to interpret values out of a TC1 capacitor tester to determine if a cap is bad?
I just got myself a TC1 capacitor tester with a bunch of replacement caps for a couple devices that I own.
I was wondering how to actually read the values out of the TC1 to determine if the capacitor is going bad.  For instance, I have this supposedly new Nichicon 470uF/16V axial capacitor and I am looking at a 444uF reading with 2.7% Vloss and ESR=0.85ohm.
How do I know which if any of those values are indicating that the cap is good or going bad?


Welcome! What does the datasheet say about capacitance tolerance and ESR/loss factor?

Why is my question already downvoted? The datasheet says tolerance:20%.  It does not seem to say anything about ESR or loss factor.

With 20 % tolerance, 444/470 is well within specification. 850 mohm sounds relaistic for an electrolytic of this size, but if it's some special super low ESR-type, it could be out of spec. Please post a link to the datasheet.

Thanks @winny ! It's not mentioned anywhere in the ads or datasheet that this particular cap is a low-ESR.  The datasheet is here, should I add it to my question? https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/AE080APQ12/470uF+470+uF+16V+Axial+Electrolytic+Capacitors+Nichicon+TPC1C471M.html

Part is obsolete so no datasheet available. You need to know the test frequency but let's assume the 0.15 % in your link is same as your tester, then ESR is more than one order of magnitude too high. Replace?

That capacitor is supposed to be brand new, so I think I got screwed over.  Would you think the same thing?

That doesn't sound too far from normal. Here's the chart from the classic 'Dick Smith' ESR meter:

As the manual says, look for values perhaps an order of magnitude higher than shown in the chart for a bad capacitor.
Modern low impedance capacitors have much lower ESR, but that's not what you have. Typical capacitance tolerance is -20/+80% and meters like you have are not all that accurate, so everything looks okay to me. Somewhere around 1Ω or less is normal for a moderate size old-fashioned electrolytic capacitor. I don't even see an ESR figure mentioned in that horrible low-resolution scan.
If you're trying to replace a modern low-ESR cap (for example, in a switching power supply) you've ordered the wrong kind of capacitor. It would be fine for most mains-frequency linear supply circuits.

So according to that table (which I also saw elsewhere earlier today) 470uF/16V should be near 0.2ohm... This means that 0.85ohm is 400% what the table says it's supposed to be.  Are you sure it's sounds normal? The one I'm replacing is exactly the same kind, an electrolytic axial capacitor that looks identical in shape and value.  I guess I will de-solder the older one and compare both in the tester to see which one has the best values then?

It sounds normal enough to me. Sure, check the old one.
